# Informal or formal? "mind your p's and q's"

Tags: informal-language

"mind your p's and q's"

Is this phrase formal or informal?

Comment: [Informal](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mind+your+p%27s+and+q%27s)

Answer (score 1):

This is an idiom, meaning "mind your manners" or "obey the rules of etiquette". It is now rather old-fashioned, and I would expect to see it only in fiction set before 1940 or so, or in works dating from that time. When it was in current use, it was used mainly as an instruction from an adult to a child, and would not have been often used in formal writing. It was not so much informal as specialized, I would say.